# Is it possible to use XPath 1.0 Function in a Content Control DataBinding?

Tags: xml, xpath, ms-word, office-js, openxml

I am trying to bind a content control using a [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.databinding?view=openxml-2.8.1) tag in Microsoft Word through the Office JavaScript API. That works fine for XPath expressions that target a single element, however when I try to use any [XPath 1.0 function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#corelib), I receive an error.

Microsofts documentation does (given my understanding) neither specify which XPath Version can be used, nor if XPath or XSLT functions are supported.

Looking at [ECMA-376 Section 17.5.2.6](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) it explicitly says:

> Specifies the XPath expression that shall be evaluated to find the custom XML node that is mapped to the nearest ancestor structured document tag. This XPath expression shall be specified using the syntax defined in the XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0 specification (see Annex A for bibliographic reference information).
>
> [Example: Consider the following structured document tag properties:
>
> `<w:sdtPr> <w:dataBinding w:xpath="//ns0:book" w:prefixMappings="xmlns:ns0= 'http://example.com/example'"/> <w:text/>`

I am wondering if it is possible to bind a content control to an XPath expression that uses a XPath function like `number()` or any other function.

Comment: How does your sample expression look like exactly, which error exactly do you get?

Comment: `column: 102
 line: 163
 message: "Type error"
 sourceURL: "https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/?backButton=true&officejs=https%3A%2F%2Fappsforoffice.microsoft.com%2Flib%2Fbeta%2Fhosted%2Foffice.js"
 stack: "evaluate@[native code] @https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/?`

My sample expression is `number(//foo/bar[1]/text())`, given a customXML Part like this:

`...
<foo><bar>123</bar></foo>`

As I am using customXML Parts in Javascript I am using the beta API library.

Comment: I have never used that stuff but the spec suggests you can map an XML element to a word document element, not an arbitrary XPath value. So the Path as e.g. `//foo/bar[1]` should work (as probably e.g. `//foo/bar[sum(baz) > 10]`, to use an expression still selecting an element node but using an XPath function), but I don't think you can map a numeric value returned by e.g. a `number` call to the Word element.

Comment: @MartinHonnen is correct. It's XPath 1.0 only, XML 1 (.1 I think) and where you can use XSLT in Word (not here) it's also v1. You can map a content control to an element or an attribute in an XML Custom Part, but you cannot use it to specify the content control's value directly (which I think is what you are trying to do). Mapping to anything except a leaf Element is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @jonsson for the answer. Indeed that is what I am trying to do. Why do you consider this not a good idea?
Sidenode: XPath 1.0 indeed has a lot of functions built in, as you can see in the link from the specification in my question.

Comment: No problem with the *idea* of assigning a value directly, but Word just doesn't allow it. I was mainly warning off assigning to nonleaf Elements because then you're going to lose child/descendent Elements.